# URL is not opening in headless chrome using Selenium java and windows os

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, headless

I am  facing below issue while running scripts on chrome headless using Selenium java and in Windows OS.
URL is not opening i am getting null as a title of page for my application URL..chrome driver version 2.33 ,chrome browser 62..I am using below code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromedriver.exe);
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
chromeOptions.addArguments("window-sized1200,600");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
driver.get("app url");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle)
```

Is it because by app URL is not supported headless mode ..not getting any exception..

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your window size argument and you call `addArguments` but you only add one argument per call, try this

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("headless", "window-size=1200,600");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
driver.get("your.app.url");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but it is still not working..is there any perquisites  to check if URL is compatible for headless automation or not?

Comment: @AmrutaPande firstly please try with http://www.google.com. Then you will be able to check whether your url is ok for headless or not.   There is nothing wrong with the answer. The answer is perfect.

Comment: Hey thanks replyin...I do check the other URL they are working fine but not mine:( it means my app URL is not compatible?

Comment: Would you mind sharing your url? Does it work when not running headless?

Comment: Yes..it works without headless mode.. unfortunately I can't share the link as it is official one ..is there any way to find out if URL is compatible to headless or not?

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider a couple of changes as follows :

- While you do **System.setProperty** provide the `absolute path` of the **`chromedriver`** binary.

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
  ```
- The `argument` for **window-size** is **`options.addArguments("window-size=1400,600");`**

  ```
  chromeOptions.addArguments("window-size=1400,600");
  ```
- While you do **driver.get()** include the **`https`** and **`www`**

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
  ```
- To retrive the **Page Title** the method is **`getTitle()`**

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
  ```
- Your modified code block will look like :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
  ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
  chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
  chromeOptions.addArguments("window-size=1400,600");
  WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
  driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
  System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
  ```